# React hook form - TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined at L (get.ts:6)

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, reactstrap, react-hook-form

Using create react app with react hook form and reactstrap. It throws the above error. got few answers like it is because of the missing name attribute in the controller. I am not using a controller. It occurs only after taking a build.

Below you could find the full code.

```
 const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({
    mode: "onSubmit",
    reValidateMode: "onBlur",
  });
 <Form className="Login" onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitHandler)}>
        <h1 className="mb-4">Log in</h1>
        <FormGroup className={errors.email ? "mb-2" : "mb-4"}>
          <Label for="email" hidden>
            Email
          </Label>
          <Input
            type="text"
            data-test="component-field"
            name="email"
            innerRef={register({ required: true })}
            id="email"
            placeholder="Email"
            defaultValue={email}
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          />
          {errors.email && (
            <span className="text-danger mb-1 p-1">This field is required</span>
          )}
        </FormGroup>{" "}
        <FormGroup className={errors.password ? "mb-2" : "mb-4"}>
          <Label for="password" hidden>
            Password
          </Label>
          <Input
            type="password"
            data-test="component-field"
            name="password"
            innerRef={register({ required: true })}
            defaultValue={password}
            id="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            ref={register({ required: true })}
          />
          {errors.password && (
            <span className="text-danger mb-1 p-1">This field is required</span>
          )}
        </FormGroup>{" "}
        <Button size="sm" className="wb-primary-button font-weight-bold">
          Login
        `</Button>`
```

Comment: i think your usage is incorrect, you shouldn't really see setState while using react hook form. I would suggest taking a look at the section with Controller.

Comment: I showed only the form codes. I had the setState function in my code. I used ref in the second input field that is an issue. thanks for responding.

Answer (score 1):

got an answer from GitHub discussion from its author. since I used reactstrap library, I should use innerRef instead of ref that throws an error. In second Input element removed ref then it worked fine.